# How to handle uploaded files in PrimeNG

Tags: spring, angular, spring-mvc, file-upload

Angular newbie here.

In my angular project I need to deliver a file upload feature.
I am using PrimeNg FileUpload since it looks easy to use. I am able to make it work by specifying the necessary attributes provided in the PrimeNG tutorial.

Problem is I am using Angular 2 along with Spring MVC and rest API.
Although I am able to upload files the function is purely on the client side. I am not able to pass the file objects to my spring controller and be able to manipulate it from there.

Could anyone please tell me how to pass the uploaded files from PrimeNg file upload to my spring controller? Thank you in advance :D :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client-side implementation of the file-upload is irrelevant, the server just sees a `multipart/form-data` request.

We're using this approach:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/your/path", 
    method = RequestMethod.POST, 
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
    consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public YourResponseRepresentation uploadContent(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

    // You can now access the file's input stream, file name, ...
}
```

See `org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile` for details on what's available to use (part op Spring MVC). We're using the **Apache Commons FileUpload** implementation to do the heavy lifting of the multipart under the hood and offer you a simple stream to read from.

Just add the appropriate `commons-fileupload` version as dependency and you're ready to go...

Comment: Wow!! this worked for me thanks :D

Although since we're here can i ask all the way.. How would the back end code be if my fileupload accepts multiple uploading at once? 
Your suggestion works perfectly for single file upload but tends to break down when i upload multiple files.

Thanks again. :D :)

Comment: Depends on the implementation of the primeFaces file upload: Does it do a `multipart/form-data` POST for every file selected or does it group all the files in a single POST, with multiple parts/form-fields?

Comment: it groups all files in a single post, with multiple parts. :)

Comment: Although luckily i found out how to do this by changing some parameters on your initial suggestion. Thanks for all the help :)